# Is it possible to send email by multiple sender using javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail

Is it possible to send Email by multiple authenticated sender one by one automatically using javamail..? How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but you need to explain in more detail what you mean by "automatically".  The simple solution is to use a separate Session for each sender and send each message one at a time.  That's so obvious that you must be asking for something else.

Comment: Thanks Bill...I want to send Email by 100 senders to single recipient in a continuous loop. So how can I implement it. If possible by using csv file then how to read the sender from file and then how to get it into main program..

Comment: It sounds like you're asking a relatively basic programming question that has nothing to do with JavaMail.  I'm sure if you search for "how to read a csv file with Java" you'll get lots of answers.